# Xamarin Studio e Monodevelop são a mesma IDE?

Tags: c#, xamarin, monodevelop

Olá, vou começar a programar em C#, mas não quero usar o Visual Studio, então procurei e achei uma outra IDE, o Monodevelop, mas quando fui baixar, para Windows 10, o site dizia para baixar o Xamarin Studio. Gostaria de saber se esse Xamarin Studio é o Monodevelop ou se são coisas de diferentes. Se não são queria saber se posso usar livremente o Xamarin Studio para desenvolver. Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Xamarin Studio é o MonoDevelop com os *addins* e marca do Xamarin. [Veja nesse tweet do desenvolvedor principal do projeto.](https://twitter.com/migueldeicaza/status/304269710520905728) É código aberto e está no [GitHub](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop).

Se quiser usar o Xamarin Studio sem Xamarin, é só desativar os addins e usá-lo como se utilizava o MonoDevelop. Tudo que se faz no MonoDevelop, pode-se fazer no Xamarin Studio.

Da [página de downloads do MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/):

> Para Mac e Windows, você pode baixar o Xamarin Studio, que é um pacote do MonoDevelop com a marca e os plugins do Xamarin iOS/Android. Note que uma licença do Xamarin é requerida somente se desenvolverá em projetos iOS/Android, todos os outros projetos são grátis e sem restrições.